# how to append a div through JQuery like the eCommerce website on click or focus

Tags: php, jquery, html

This is my HTML code

```
<div>
    <div class="text-center col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 animate-box">
        <div class="team-section-grid" style="background-image: url(assets/img/image-bg.jpg);">
            <div class="overlay-section">
                <div class="desc">
                    <a href="product?id=1" title="" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon icon-wallet2"></i> &nbsp;Buy Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center add-cart">
            <a href="" title="">
                <i class="icon icon-cart"></i> &nbsp;Add To Cart
            </a>
            <a href="" title="">
                <i class="icon icon-heart" style="margin-left: 10px;"></i> &nbsp;Add To Wishlist
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
   View More..
</div>
```

What i am trying to achieve through JQUery is whenever click the view more.. or whenever the focus is on that button I want the following div appended to the current div so that I can dynamically load products from the DB and append it.

Can anyone help me with that code? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried: http://api.jquery.com/append/ ?

A very simple example:

```js
jQuery('.wrapper a').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault;
  
  jQuery('.wrapper').append('<div class="item"></div>');
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  padding: 10px 10px 50px 10px;
}

.wrapper a{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: #aaa;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 3px solid #fff;
  }

.item{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#">show more</a>
  
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Instead of `append('<div class="item"></div>')` you can append html-templates, too. It could be more comfortable to use a template engine here ...